# How to connect a switch with a router via another switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, packet-tracer

[image]

**ROUTER CONFIG**

```
Router#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 769 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description connecting to switch0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.224
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.10.34 255.255.255.224
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**Switch0 config**

```
Switch#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1293 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description connecting to router
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 description connecting to switch1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 description connecting to a pc which is in vlan10
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**switch1 config**

```
Switch#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1237 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description connecting to a pc which is in vlan 20
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 description connecting to switch0
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**ROUTER cdp neighbours**

```
Router#sh cdp neighbors 
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone
Device ID    Local Intrfce   Holdtme    Capability   Platform    Port ID
Router#
```

**switch0 cdp neighbours**

```
 Switch#sh cdp neighbors 
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone
Device ID    Local Intrfce   Holdtme    Capability   Platform    Port ID
Switch       Fas 0/2          141            S       2960        Fas 0/2
Router       Fas 0/1          138            R       C2800       Fas 0/0
Router       Fas 0/1          138            R       C2800       Fas 0/0.10
Router       Fas 0/1          138            R       C2800       Fas 0/0.20
```

**switch1 neighbours**

```
Switch#sh cdp neighbors 
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone
Device ID    Local Intrfce   Holdtme    Capability   Platform    Port ID
Switch       Fas 0/2          175            S       2960        Fas 0/2
Switch#
```

the router doesnt show any neighbours

Comment: You are missing the configuration of one switch. Please edit the question to include that, and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: You should also take advantage of the `description` command on each interface to explain to what other device and interface the link connects., and the output of the `show cdp neighbor` command is useful.

Comment: @RonMaupin added the other switch config and cdp neighbours of router and switches. For the description, routers 0/0.x sub interface's x indicates the vlan it is referring to. Switch's 0/1 are trunked to each other switches and left switch's 0/2 is trunked to the router. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why does the right switch say it is connected to the router in CDP? Also, the router does not show any neighbors? You should also name the switches differently so that we can tell the difference. What I meant by the description is the `description` command. For instance, the first switch could have under its `interface FastEthernet0/2` something like `description *** to Switch2 F0/2 ***`. This is a habit you should get into, then you can use CDP and the description to make sure things are correctly connected.

Comment: @RonMaupin completely edited the original post to make it easy for you. Please help

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: @RonMaupin Worked like a charm, sir! Rookie mistake. I was not creating both VLANs on each switch. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That's good. You should really get in the practice of using descriptions on interfaces (including sub-interfaces and SVIs, even those that are not in use can be labeled `UNUSED` or something), VLAN names, and any other thing in the network devices that can take some type of label.. Developing that habit will serve you well in the real world, and it helps a lot when troubleshooting large/complex networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin Will keep this in mind, sir. Thanks a lot for your time and help. And I have a couple of questions to answer for the assignment. You have already done enough help to me. Please only answer if you have spare time, otherwise totally not a problem.


1. What is meant by networking principles? (are they referring to protocols? The google search results explain about topologies and protocols and stuff. So I'm unclear about the question.

2. The operating principles of networking devices. (Are they referring to OSI layers of devices?)

Opened a new thread and was told not allowed.

Comment: The problem with your questions is that they really depend on the context in which they were asked. We have not attended your class, so we cannot answer them. The questions are not really based on standard language, and they are for your course, not the real world.

Comment: @RonMaupin Aaah this helps. I can write what I had learnt without worrying about 
 others definitions. You, sir, is great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you are not creating the VLANs on the switches.

The easiest way to do that is as a global command on each switch:

```
VLan 10
 name <vlan name, no spaces, use underscores>
!
VLan 20
 name <vlan name, no spaces, use underscores>
!
```

Answer (score 1):

For inter -Vlan routing router configuration seems to be correct . Create Vlan 10 & Vlan 20 on both switch and check for status .

Please make sure ip address ,subnet ,gateway are correctly configuration on both PCs connected to both switch on vlan 10 and Vlan 20 .